# How to solve a Box Claw mover so it spread all boxes evenly on all available stacks?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a Robotic Claw lever puzzle, which should spread all boxes across all available stacks evenly.

[image]

The problem is that when it reaches the last box, it moves LEFT and then RIGHT, looping infinitely.:

```js
function solve(clawPos, boxes, boxInClaw) {
  // Calculate a maximum number of boxes per stack
  let max = (boxes.reduce((a, b) => a + b) + ~~boxInClaw) / boxes.length

  // Current stack number
  const current = boxes[clawPos]

  // Helpers
  const bigger = current > max
  const lower = current < max
  const equal = current === max
  const last = clawPos === boxes.length - 1

  // Command to return for a claw
  let command = ''

  // Actions for claw
  const R = () => command = 'RIGHT'
  const L = () => command = 'LEFT'
  const U = () => command = 'PICK'
  const D = () => command = 'PLACE'

  // Automatically select where to move the claw
  const autoDirection = () => {
    const value = boxes[clawPos]
    const left = boxes.slice(0, clawPos)
    const right = boxes.slice(clawPos, -1)

    const target = max - 1

    if (boxInClaw) {
      if (left.includes(target)) L()
      else if (right.includes(target)) R()
    } else {
      R()
    }
  }

  autoDirection()

  if (boxInClaw) {
    if (lower) D()
  } else {
    if (bigger) U()
  }

  return command;
}
```

I've tried to many different approaches to make it dynamic, is there any smarter approach to know at which direction it should go?

Here is a direct link (please, DO NOT submit): https://www.codingame.eu/evaluate/18917274?id=427696529803c1cd24e9258b89d01a98a72126e

Comment: Why are you checking clawpos = 0/1 when its range is [1, 8] ? It means it will not return any command once the current is away from 2nd position. Total no. of boxes can be 16 and stacks can be 8 so why 0/1?

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan, as I said, it's hardcoded to make it pass only the first test case, and I'm now trying to make it dynamic so it will adapt to all test scenarios.

Comment: Were you able to solve it on pen and paper with multiple test cases? Did you land up on an algorithm? For the dynamic part it won't be any issue since boxes.length will give you the limit of positions and clawPos is already giving the current index. The boxes array has the stack info and the last argument says if the arm holds anything or not. But the most important thing is the algorithm

Comment: Try to see it this way I haven't done it on paper so I can't be confident about it. You check the status of clawPos stack and boxInClaw. 1. Do u need to put it down? 2. Do you need to pick it up? 3. Should it go left? 4. Should it go right?

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan - I've updated my OP with a working code except it's not ideal :

Comment: So all test cases passed?

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan yeah, I've done it yesterday, but the code was modified to pass all tests, but having only 30 minutes for this task with 10 different test scenarios is pretty much impossible for me, to be honest

Comment: Its not impossible. You just need to practice more n more. Keep practicing DS Algo and you'll solve questions even faster than before. Tests are always designed to be doable.

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution to that:

```js
function createStack(length, totalBoxes) {
  const boxPerStack = Math.floor(totalBoxes / length);
  let newStack = new Array(length).fill(boxPerStack);

  const remainder = totalBoxes % length;
  if (remainder !== 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < remainder; i++) {
      newStack[i]++;
    }
  }

  return newStack;
}

function solve(clawPos, boxes, boxInClaw) {
  // Write your code here
  const totalBoxes = boxes.reduce((prev, acc) => prev + acc);
  let targetPos;

  if (boxInClaw) {
    const targetStack = createStack(boxes.length, totalBoxes + 1);

    // Move to place
    for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
      if (boxes[i] < targetStack[i]) {
        targetPos = i;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (clawPos === targetPos) return 'PLACE';
    else if (clawPos < targetPos) return 'RIGHT';
    else return 'LEFT';
  } else {
    const targetStack = createStack(boxes.length, totalBoxes);

    // Move to pick
    for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
      if (boxes[i] > targetStack[i]) {
        targetPos = i;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (clawPos === targetPos) return 'PICK';
    else if (clawPos < targetPos) return 'RIGHT';
    else return 'LEFT';
  }

  return '';
}
```